# WP Query not working DESC

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following query:

```
<?php $postslist = new WP_Query('meta_key=Ordermetakey&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5');
```

To sort a small post list on the frontpage to show latest new. It needs to order them by a meta key and do this DESC. The strange thing is it shows the posts ASC even though i have put ASC in this query.

The value of the meta key is a date - time stamp:
Example: 120403  = 03-04-2012

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

have u tried this
and it works only on home page

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) ;?>
<?php
$recentposts=get_posts('showposts=5');
if ($recentposts) {
foreach($recentposts as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<p><?php the_time('m.d.y') ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent     Link to 
<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php
}
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No i need to order the posts on my custom field.